# C - how to exclude other inputs in a y/n loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I am trying to get a simple y/n input to work. I have it working and it will break a while(1) loop when n or N is entered, however, any other alphabetical character will set the loop to go again. I only want it to loop when Y is entered.

I have tried:
 `if (try_another != 'n' || try_another != 'N' || try_another != 'y' || try_another != 'Y')`, after the `!isalpha` line, and this did not work.

I have tried `scanf (" %c", try_another);` and then comparing the assigned characters.

this is my current code set up:

```
printf("Do you wish to try another problem [y/n]: ");

        do{
            try_another = getchar();
        /*keeps scanning for input until its a letter*/
        }while(!isalpha(try_another));
    /*when input is n or N it will end the program*/
        if (try_another == 'n' || try_another == 'N'){
            break;
        }
```

Comment: It really sounds like you want another loop around all of this. So the inner loop only makes sure a valid entry was given, in your case that would be y/Y/n/N and then the outer loop exits if you had n/N but not for y/Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do this?

```
do {
    try_another = getchar();
} while(try_another != 'n' && try_another != 'N' && try_another != 'y' && try_another != 'Y');
```

You want to loop while the character isn't this **and** isn't that. You were *close*, but accidentally wrote "or" instead of "and".

Comment: ~That caused the program to crash~

No, scratch that, I just forgot to comment out a line. Thank you, it worked

Comment: @Pepper If this solved your problem, you can click the green "tick" to accept it.

Comment: I upvoted, but as i am new, it didn't count. your reply sorted out my problems, so thank you!